# What is regex match with caption : [name]?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to match the regex to the format "caption: [name]" ? I have used

```
^ ([a-zA-Z0-9]) + (. *?) + \: + (. *?) + $
```

but failed.

Comment: The `+` signs should not be necessary at most points. They mean something other than concatenation

Comment: Also, you are not mathing the square brackets. Try using a website that shows you what matches your regex

Comment: any solustion ?

Comment: Do you want to capture/extract the `"name"`?

Comment: Please [mark an answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark next to it

Answer (score 1):

In your current regex you have lots of problems

- `^` - This means match space after start of string whereas your input string doesn't have any
- `([a-zA-Z0-9])+` - This means match group one or more time, i.e this tries to match repetitive characters
- `(. *?)` - This means match any one character followed by zero or more space characters
- `+` - This means one or more space characters

You can use

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*:\s*\[[^\]]+\]$/
```

[image]

```js
let str = "caption: [name]" 

let reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*:\s*\[[^\]]+\]$/

console.log(reg.test(str))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you wish to design an expression similar to:

```
^([^:]+)\s*:\s*(\[[^\]]+\])$
```

and capture `caption` and `[name]`.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/c0iaQc/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

```js
const regex = /^([^:]+)\s*:\s*(\[[^\]]+\])$/gm;
const str = `caption: [name]
other_captions: [other_names]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern you use spaces which have meaning. If you would remove all the spaces, your pattern would match and look like the following having 3 capturing groups:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9])+(.*?)+\:+(.*?)+$
```

**About the pattern**

When you repeat the group using a quantifier (in this case `+`), the group contains the value of the last iteration so you could move the quantifier inside the group.

The first group matches until `caption`. You could omit `(.*?)+` as `:` is the next char and will be matched by `\:+`.

That part itself can be written as `:` because you don't have to escape the colon and you want to match a single `:`.

The second group is not taking the opening and closing square brackets into account. This could be matched using `(\[.*?\])` or more efficient using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `(\[[^]]+\])`

If you want to keep the capturing groups, you pattern might look like:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+): (\[[^\]]+\])$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WNY1Lv/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right, thank you. I have updated it.